# Position and adding another input node

Tags: tikz-pgf

Currently, I have something like this

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
                    \node [draw=black,
                    minimum width=3cm,
                    minimum height=1.2cm,
                    ]  (controller) {1};
                    
                    \node [draw=black,
                    minimum width=3cm, 
                    minimum height=1.2cm, 
                    right=0.8cm of controller
                    ]  (sensor) {2};
                    
                    \node [draw=black,
                    minimum width=3cm, 
                    minimum height=1.2cm, 
                    right=0.8cm of sensor
                    ]  (system) {3};
                    
                    \draw[-stealth] (system.south) -- +(0,-0.39) -| node[pos=0.25,above]{x} (sensor.south);
                    \draw[-stealth] (controller.east) --  node[pos=0.5,above]{$u_{no}$} (sensor.west);
                    \draw[-stealth] (sensor.east) --  node[pos=0.5,above]{$u$} (system.west);
                    
                    \draw[-stealth] (system.east) -- ++ (1.25,0) 
                    node[midway](output){}node[midway,above]{$y_{out}$};
                    
                    \draw[-stealth] (output.center) -- +(0,-1.5) -| node[pos=0.25,above]{} (controller.west);
                \end{tikzpicture}
```

What to change such that my first block has two inputs like here? How to add another one? How to position it nicely? How to change this existing node such that it isnt't directly near the block?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete the last line of code

```
\draw[-stealth] (output.center) -- +(0,-1.5) -| node[pos=0.25,above]{} (controller.west);
```

and add the following two lines

```
\draw[-stealth] (output.center) -- +(0,-1.5) -| node[pos=0.25,above]{} ($(controller.west)+(-2ex,-2ex)$) -- ($(controller.west)+(0ex,-2ex)$);

\draw[-stealth] ($(controller.west) + (-4ex,0ex)$) -- (controller.west) ;
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc,backgrounds}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
                    \node [draw=black,
                    minimum width=3cm,
                    minimum height=1.2cm,
                    ]  (controller) {1};
                    
                    \node [draw=black,
                    minimum width=3cm, 
                    minimum height=1.2cm, 
                    right=0.8cm of controller
                    ]  (sensor) {2};
                    
                    \node [draw=black,
                    minimum width=3cm, 
                    minimum height=1.2cm, 
                    right=0.8cm of sensor
                    ]  (system) {3};
                    
                    \draw[-stealth] (system.south) -- +(0,-0.39) -| node[pos=0.25,above]{x} (sensor.south);
                    \draw[-stealth] (controller.east) --  node[pos=0.5,above]{$u_{no}$} (sensor.west);
                    \draw[-stealth] (sensor.east) --  node[pos=0.5,above]{$u$} (system.west);
                    
                    \draw[-stealth] (system.east) -- ++ (1.25,0) 
                    node[midway](output){}node[midway,above]{$y_{out}$};
                    
                    \draw[-stealth] (output.center) -- +(0,-1.5) -| node[pos=0.25,above]{} ($(controller.west)+(-2ex,-2ex)$) -- ($(controller.west)+(0ex,-2ex)$);

                    \draw[-stealth] ($(controller.west) + (-4ex,0ex)$) -- (controller.west) ;
                    
                \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```